# drupal 8 create an page in admin section in admin/structure/customformdatalisting

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to create a custom admin page in drupal 8 admin
i have create a custom module name custom_admin also I have added the below code in

```
"custom_admin.routing.xml"
custom_admin.contactformlisting:
  path: '/admin/structure/contactformlisting'
  defaults:
    _content: 
'\Drupal\custom_admin\Controller\AdminController::contactformlisting'
    _title: 'Contact Form Listing'
requirements:
    _permission: 'administer contact forms listing'  
   _access: 'TRUE'
```

### custom_admin_permissions.yml

```
administer contact forms listing:
  title: 'Administer contact forms listing'
```

in custom_admin.links,menu.yml

```
custom_admin.contactformlisting:
  title: Contact Form Data Listing 
  description: 'This is a contact form listing page link`enter code here`'
  parent: system.admin_structure
  route_name: custom_admin.contactformlisting
```

But still revceving Page not Found can anybody help me in these

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's just a typo above, but the file "custom_admin.routing.xml" should be `custom_admin.routing.yml*` (yml instead of xml). The permissions yml needs to be module_name.permissions.yml - you have module_name_permissions.yml (underscore instead of period).

I also notice some spacing issues in the routing file for `_access:`(again not sure if just a typo here), but yml format is very specific. They need to all be indented 2 spaces.

If it's still not working, I would suggest removing the `_access` property altogether from the routing yml and set `_permission: TRUE` temporarily, just to remove any other variables that could be interfering.